# SwiftUI Published updates not refreshing

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to manage user state via a series of nested classes.

The basic view of the app uses a `globalState` environment object. This object allows other views to the user in and out.

```swift
@EnvironmentObject var globalState: GlobalState

// View Code
Text("Logged In").opacity(globalState.user.isLoggedIn ? 1 : 0)
Text("Please Sign In").opacity(globalState.user.isLoggedIn ? 0 : 1)
```

Then the `GlobalState` class merely houses the `User` class. The `user` field is init'ed elsewhere (and no, I'm not referencing different `user` objects).

```swift
class GlobalState: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var user: User // Inited somewhere else
}
class User {
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
}
```

The `User` class automatically pulls data about the user when it is `init`ed. On app launch, user information is pulled from the Keychain (if present). If the user can be created from existing data, that user's `isLoggedIn` is set to `true`.

I know I do not have duplicate objects, as the memory addresses of the `globalState.user` in `GlobalState`'s View Code is the same as when `isLoggedIn` is updated for a user.

I feel a disturbance in the Force by using two levels of `@Published` variables, but everything should work out?

The view code in `GlobalState` does not update though. Any one know why? Some Combine jiu jitsu I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Published` publishes value changes, so if you would replace the User object it would update. Since User is a class (Reference type) it will not update the value of GlobalState.user when User.isLoggedIn changes.

Fix for this is [this package called NestedPublished](https://github.com/Amzd/NestedPublished) which sends the nested ObservableObject.willChange to its parent.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Minimal refactoring needed to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

`ObservedObject` observes only one level of published properties, if you have hierarchy of `ObservableObject` instances, you need to separated dependent views with own `ObservedObject` for each such case.

```
@EnvironmentObject var globalState: GlobalState

// View Code - separated explicit subview
UserLoginStateView(user: globalState.user)
```

and

```
struct UserLoginStateView: View {
   @ObservedObject var user: User

   var body: some View {
      Group {
         Text("Logged In").opacity(user.isLoggedIn ? 1 : 0)
         Text("Please Sign In").opacity(user.isLoggedIn ? 0 : 1)
      }
   }
}
```