# SwiftUI identifiable ForEach doesn't update when initially starting with empty

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a SwiftUI app that fetches some information from the backend when the view appears and then attempts to update the State by setting `@Published` vars in an `ObservableObject`. The problem I have is it doesn't update at first fetch (it remains empty since it was initialized with an empty array) but if I click to another view and come back it's updated (since the information was already fetched).

Obviously, the intended thing I'm going for with using `@Published` is for the view to update once the information is fetched. This is part of a larger app but I have the reduced version of what I have below.

First, we have a parent view that contains the view I want to update.

```
struct ParentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                SummaryView()
                // In real life I have various forms of summary
                // but to simplify here I will just use this one SummaryView.
                SummaryView()
                SummaryView()
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the summary view itself:

```
struct SummaryView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model = AccountsSummaryViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Accounts")
                    .font(.title)
                
                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: AccountView(),
                    label: {
                        Image("RightArrow")
                    })
                
            }
            
            if model.accounts.count > 0 {
                Divider()
            }
            
            // And if I add the following line for debugging
            //Text(model.accounts.count)
            // It remains 0.

            ForEach(model.accounts, id: \.id) { account in
                Text(account.account.text)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
            model.onAppear()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is it's simple view model:

```
class AccountsSummaryViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var accounts: [AccountIdentifiable] = []
    
    func onAppear() {
        
        AccountsService.accounts { (success, error, response) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // This always succeeds
                if let response = response {
                    
                    // All AccountIdentifiable does is make a struct that is Identifiable (has an account and a var id = UUID())
                    self.accounts = Array(response.accounts.map { AccountIdentifiable(account: $0) }.prefix(3))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Here is the contents of the AccountsService also, I will note that the URL is a localhost but I'm not sure if that matters:

```
public struct AccountsService {
    
    public static func accounts(completion: @escaping ((Bool, Error?, AccountsResponse?) -> Void)) {
        guard let url = getAllAccountsURL() else {
            completion(false, nil, nil)
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                                       BusinessConstants.SET_COOKIE : CredentialsObject.shared.jwt]

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(false, error, nil)
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AccountsResponse.self, from: data) else {
                completion(false, error, nil)
                return
            }

            // This does successfully decode and return here. 
            completion(true, nil, response)
            
            return
        }

        task.resume()

    }
    
    private static func getAllAccountsURL() -> URL? {
        let address = "\(BusinessConstants.SERVER)/plaid/accounts"

        return URL(string: address)
    }
    
}
```

I have read that there are issues with an empty `ScrollView`, however, my `ScrollView` is never empty as I have those static text elements. I also read that if you use a `ForEach` without the *id* it can fail - but you can see I am using the *id* so I'm kind of at a loss.

I have print statements in the `onAppear()` so I know it runs and successfully sets the `@Published accounts` but looking at the UI and putting breakpoints in the `ForEach` I can see the view does not update. However, if I navigate somewhere else in my app, and then come back to the `ParentView` then since the `@Published accounts` is non-empty (already fetched) it updates perfectly.

Comment: It is not possible to replicate behaviour of your `AccountsService.accounts`, but if I replace it with simple deferred update all works fine, so it is not with UI, it is something with service + model layers.

Comment: just added the AccountsService @Asperi

Comment: Wouldn't changing model in SummaryView to @StateObject solve your problem?

Comment: @LuLuGaGa yeah it turns out I was improperly using ObservedObject and should’ve been using StateObject upon changing it it seems to have solved the problem. When I open up the app the views properly load now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not working was due to the fact that I was using `@ObservedObject` instead of `@StateObject` in SummaryView. Making the change fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running into a problem because of the two levels of observed objects, with `model: AccountsSummaryViewModel` containing `accounts: [AccountIdentifiable]`.

SwiftUI will only watch one level, leading to your `ParentView` not updating when `accounts` is set *more than one* UI level down.

As [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65194585/swiftui-published-updates-not-refreshing), one option is to use [PublishedObject](https://github.com/Amzd/NestedPublished) via the Swift Package Manager in Xcode. Changing `model` in your `SummaryView` to `@PublishedObject` may be all that's required to fix this.